# Highlighting when a question has 0 other answers in review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9064474) in the Low Quality review queue. Before my edit (and probably a little bit now) it just read as a "Thanks" post. But if you look at the question page and read the answer closely, you'll notice that they're actually saying

> "Thanks to [source not on SO] I discovered that the solution was [useful answer]".

It could do with improvement and a proper demonstration but it's not worthy of deletion. However it was tagged as recommended for deletion multiple times, presumably because it looked like a thanks post, even if it didn't quite smell like one. I think in cases like this it would be good to highlight clearer that there are no other answers on this post. The current placement is clearly just noting it as ancillary data that you won't generally pay attention to.

[image: Screenshot of review layout]

This could also be useful for link only answers, where if a bad post is the only post then perhaps it's worth editing the answer into proper shape rather than outright deleting it.